# *ngFor - update dom when array updates through ngrx

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am using *ngFor to display values from an array:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'item1'
  },   
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'item2'
  }
]
```

html:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of (items$ | async); trackBy: trackById;">
   // more html to display data
</div
```

ts:

```
items$: Observable<any>;
trackById = trackByProperty('id');

ngOnInit() {
  this.items$ = this.store.pipe(select(selectors.itemsSelector));
}

trackByProperty<T = any>(property: keyof T) {
  return (index: number, object: T) => object[property];
}
```

This works as intended, ngFor gets the correct and current values in the `items$ array`

My issue is that when I update the `items$` array using `ngrx` it doesn't seem to catch the new array and doesn't update the DOM

Heres the flow of data using `ngrx`

1. Dispatch action to the reducer, sending a new object to add to the array.

   ```
     this.store.dispatch(new actions.UpdateArray(
         { id: 3, name: 'item3' }
       )
     );
   ```
2. Reducer picks up this action and updates the store state with the updated array (receives the new item and pushes it to the array).

   ```
   case actions.UPDATE_ARRAY: {
     const newItem = action.payload;
     const items = state.items;
     items.push(newItem);
     return {
       ...state,
       items
     };
   }
   ```
3. Selector updates.

I can confirm the state gets updated correctly when logging out the action.payload in the reducer.

Does anyone know why I'm not getting an updated array in the `*ngFor`?

Forgot to mention, but I'm using `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` as my change detection in my component

### Update

I found out that the DOM actually updates when you click on the component. I'd like it to update without having to do that.

Comment: Pkt. 2, you update array with push method? If yes you should change it to spread operator which create new instance of array: return [... oldArray, newElement]

Comment: Could you post the code relevant to your store ? Actions, states, reducers, effects ...

Comment: @trichetriche ive updated my answer

Comment: @cup_of I "kind of" mocked the behavior [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r6ykdk) and it seems to work. Would you be able to reproduce your issue with that ?

Comment: @trichetriche thanks for doing that, ive updated my answer. so the dom actually does update i just need to click on the component. really strange, is there some change detection errors going on?

Comment: @cup_of seems strange indeed. It would mean your view isn't updated, which is in contradiction with the reactive programming that triggers a change detection. That's a really strange issue ! Try reproducing on stackblitz, and either post your [mcve] here or on the Angular/NgRx github repos, see what they will answer you !

Comment: I don't think that's a problem with change detection. Try `return { ...state, items: [...items, newItem] };`

If that doesn't work, you can call `detectChanges()`

Comment: @TzachOvadia that would not change a thing, since the return statement returns a new memory reference. You change change the data in it (and apparently not following the model of the OP), why would that resolve the issue ?

Comment: What does `this.store.dispatch` do ? what is `this.store` ??

Comment: @trichetriche how is the model different?

Comment: @TzachOvadia nah I misread, sorry, my bad on this one. But the first statement still stands ! Why would it resolve the issue ?

Comment: @Antoniossss basics of NgRx, the store is like a safe where you can retrieve your data, `dispatch` is the way of putting things in that safe.

Comment: @trichetriche I actually think the same as you, but I think using memoized selectors could cause weird behavior. It's a simple change (and also a good practice) so I think the OP should try it.

Comment: @TzachOvadia i tried your new return statement and it worked! thanks alot! if you want to post as an answer, ill accept it.

Comment: @trichetriche thanks for your efforts as well, and starting the conversation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might happen because NgRx selectors use Memoization which sometimes causes undesirable behavior.

Changing

```js
case actions.UPDATE_ARRAY: {
  const newItem = action.payload;
  const items = state.items;
  items.push(newItem);
  return {
    ...state,
    items
  };
}
```

to

```js
case actions.UPDATE_ARRAY: {
  const newItem = action.payload;
  const items = [...state.items, newItem]; // <-- creates new instance
  return {
    ...state,
    items
  };
}
```

should solve the problem.